# How to launch console app from terminal with parameters?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I've got console app in Xcode which uses Core Data and should get one parameter from console. Problem is it builds without packaging into .app file. So I can't even launch it from terminal, not even pass it a parameter. Maybe I missed some project settings, allowing me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should run the actual program within the app e.g. `./MyProgram.app/Contents/MacOS/MyProgram` if you are in the directory that contains the .app.

Comment: Like i said, I don't get any .app file. Just file of kind "unix executable file".

Comment: oops. just run the executable.

Comment: but terminal says it doesn't know such a command. i can use command "open", but i can't pass a parameter and get any output.

Comment: did you use ./MyApp to launch or just MyApp? the former is correct. Also, does the MyApp file have the executable bit set?

Comment: Yeah, i tried launching using ./myapp and it worked, even ate parameter. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
open -a "./MyProgram.app/Contents/MacOS/MyProgram" --args myarg
```